# When is "call" required?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I've been copying pasting some examples around and realized there is something I dont fully get.  In my test.js code(that I execute via `truffle test` I can call `await contract.getMintPrice()` fine but in my front end JS code I call `await contract.methods.getMintPrice().call()` and I realized I don't really know why?  Can someone help explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside truffle tests contract are wrapped in a [TruffleContract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract#readme) object. The wrapper allows calling methods like this:

```
await contract.getMintPrice()
```

When using web3.js contracts are wrapped in a [web3.eth.Contract](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-contract.html). It has a different syntax, and the same method should be called as

```
await contract.methods.getMintPrice().call()
```

They are two different packages each having its own syntax.